# Assign list of arrays to several columns in Pandas DataFrame (Performance-optimized)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

given the following DF:
`df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(1,10,size=(10,4)),columns=list("abcd"),dtype=np.int64)`

Lets say i want to update the first two columns with a list of two numpy arrays(having a specific dtype: e.g. np.int8 and np.float32) --> `update_vals = [np.arange(1,11,dtype=np.int8),np.ones(10,dtype=np.float32)]`

I can do the following that works: `df[["a","b"]] = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(list("ab"),update_vals)))`

Expected outcome of Column Dtypes:

- a: np.int8
- b=np.float32
- [c,d]=np.int64

Is there maybe a faster way to do this?

Comment: Hi, you are on StackOverflow, if you can make it work but you want better perfomances, you should use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If all columns had the same dtype, say float, the dataframe can store all in a (n,4) array,  But when dtypes differ, the underlying storage will have separate arrays for each dtype, if not for each column (Series).  And any no-loop operation on your 2 arrays will require converting them to one array with a uniform dtype.  Since changing dtype seems to be your priority, you have to somehow treat each array/column separately.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Why don't simply:

```
df['a'] = update_vals[0]
df['b'] = update_vals[1]
print(df.dtypes)

# Output:
a       int8
b    float32
c      int64
d      int64
dtype: object
```

Or:

```
for col, arr in zip(df.columns, update_vals):
    df[col] = arr
```

---

Use:

```
df[['a', 'b']] = np.array(update_vals).T
print(df)

# Output:
    a  b  c  d
0   1  1  1  2
1   2  1  5  1
2   3  1  4  8
3   4  1  6  3
4   5  1  3  4
5   6  1  8  2
6   7  1  3  1
7   8  1  8  7
8   9  1  4  1
9  10  1  3  6
```

Comment: Hey, no, but i think that was because of my bad questioning. Maybe you can have a look at it again

Comment: I updated my answer, can you check it please?

Comment: It does work (same as my suggest approach). I was looking for a faster way than for-looping over those columns as it is not performance-optimized if you want to update a huge amount of cols

Comment: There is no more faster than an atomic operation... `a = 1` is the fastest way to set `a` to `1`.